# numpy - index behavior difference between P[(n),(m)] and P[[n],[m]]

Tags: numpy

## Question

What is the difference between `P[(n),(m)]` and `P[[n],[m]]`? I had thought they both to select one element, hence a scalar but `()` and `[]` produce different shape. A scalar for `()` and an array for `[]`.

What is the design decisions and thoughts behind this?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(1).reshape(1, -1)
print(a)
---
[[1]]

b = a[
    (0),
    (0)
]
print(b)
print(b.shape)
print(b.ndim)
---

1
()
0

c = a[
    [0],
    [0]
]
print(c)
print(c.shape)
print(c.ndim)
---
[1]
(1,)
1
```

Comment: `numpy` does distinguish between tuples and lists in the outer layer of indexing, that is, `a[(0,1)]` is different from `a[[0,1]]`.  But with `a[[0],[1]]` and `a[(0,),(1,)]` there isn't a difference.  Note my use of commas.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in order to create a tuple with one element only, you need to add a comma.

`b = a[(0,), (0,)]` returns the same result as `c = a[[0],[0]]`.

You can try this:

```
print(type((0)))
print(type((0,)))
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

If you want to select one element only, you can simply do `a[0,0]`.